# Hom from domain to field is necessarily injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Take D to be an integral domain (commutative and unital) and take F to be a field (commutative and unital). If we have a non trivial morphism of rings from D to F is it necessarily an injection?

Comment: Can you think of a map from Z to a field with two elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the natural homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_2$ by

$f(n)=\bar{n}$

Then, $f$ is clearly a homomorphism.

Also, $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field since 2 is prime.

However, the Kernel of $f$ is all of the even integers, so clearly this is not an injection.

Comment: Hmm what if we up the ante to the target being field of char 0

Comment: Can you think of a map from Z[X]  to Q?

Comment: You should reaaaaaaaally spend much more time considering examples.

Comment: Haha, fair! Sometimes I get stuck on wanting something to be true